# Find method is throwing RecordNotFound when using parent class to search in Single Table Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to do a `find` using the parent class, it doesn't work until I use the child class first. This problem exists with Single Table Inheritance. I have my models like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = :meta_type
  scope :doctors, -> { where(meta_type: 'Doctor') }
end

class Provider < User

end

class Doctor < Provider

end
```

When I do `Provider.find(1)`, rails throws record not found. But after I do a successful `Doctor.find(1)`, `Provider.find(1)` works perfectly fine.

What could be the problem?

**EDIT**

Here are the SQL queries, notice how rails correctly makes the SQL query to include the Provider in meta_type in the third query:

`Provider.find(1)`:

```
SELECT  "public"."users".* FROM "public"."users" WHERE "public"."users"."meta_type" IN ('Provider') AND "public"."users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
```

`Doctor.find(1)`:

```
SELECT  "public"."users".* FROM "public"."users" WHERE "public"."users"."meta_type" IN ('Doctor') AND "public"."users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
```

`Provider.find(1)` (second time):

```
SELECT  "public"."users".* FROM "public"."users" WHERE "public"."users"."meta_type" IN ('Provider', 'Doctor') AND "public"."users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
```

Comment: It seems like a bug in Ruby on Rails to me.

Comment: This is caused because rails lazy loads classes. The first `Provider.find(1)` runs before Doctor is ever referenced, and therefor rails doesn't know there is a subclass called `Doctor`. Then you reference `Doctor` so the class loads. Then `Provider.find(1)` works fine. I try and avoid multilevel STI for this reason.

Comment: @ScottJacobsen as a quick hack I now just call `Doctor` to load the class. Going to have to find a way around this